# Add button below the gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview, layout

I am trying to add button to below the gridview but in my case its not working but in layout design button is display and when i am running app button is invisible please help me.I need a button below the gridview i have added button as well as gridview in layout.when i am writing a button code outside the linearlayout its working but button is not looking properly
[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cry1q.png)
Here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <!-- tools:showIn="@layout/navigation_activity_main"-->


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"

        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/searchcorner"

            app:queryHint="Search Services" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/search_layout"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="Recommended Services"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/flipper1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:flipInterval="3000"
                android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
                android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:contentDescription="ImageOne"
                    android:src="@mipmap/banner" />
            </ViewFlipper>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:columnWidth="90dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="1dp">

            </GridView>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnallservice"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_green"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="All Services"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Share the output screenshot

Comment: added screen shot @sabari

Comment: I guess the button is available under the gridview, because see the gridview's parent layout having margin-top=230dp and the gridview height is 280dp.Total height is 510dp. Could you please reduce the gridview height to 100dp and check it

Comment: use weight property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:layout_weight="1"` and change  height as `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in GridView it will work fine.

Edited :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <!-- tools:showIn="@layout/navigation_activity_main"-->


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:queryHint="Search Services" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/search_layout"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="Recommended Services"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/flipper1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:flipInterval="3000"
            android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
            android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="ImageOne"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </ViewFlipper>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/middle_item"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:columnWidth="90dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="1dp">

            </GridView>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnallservice"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="All Services"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```